# Awk to read file as a whole

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

Let a file with content as under -

```
abcdefghijklmn
pqrstuvwxyzabc
defghijklmnopq
```

In general if any operation using awk is performed, it iterates line by line and performs that action on each line.

For e.g:

```
awk '{print substr($0,8,10)}' file
```

O/P:

```
hijklmn
wxyzabc
klmnopq
```

I would like to know an approach in which all the contents inside the file is treated as a single variable and `awk` prints just one output.

Example Desired O/P:

```
hijklmnpqr
```

It's not that I wish for the desired output for the given question but in general would appreciate if anyone could suggest an approach to provide the content of a file as a whole to the awk.

Comment: You are referring to a "given question" which doesn't appear. Can you specify your "desired output" ?

Comment: If you read your question by yourself, can you understand the requirement?

Comment: @inian Isn't there a way to bypass it? Any specific flag that could help me do that?

Comment: @kent apologies but I have tried making myself as clear as I could. If you could tell me where exactly you are not understanding, I could help you elaborate myself

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### This is a `gawk` solution

From the [docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#gawk-split-records):

> There are times when you might want to **treat an entire data file as a single record**. 
>   The **only way to make this happen is to give RS a value that you know doesn’t occur in the input file**.
>   This is **hard to do in a general way**, such that a program always works for arbitrary input files.

---

```
$ cat file
abcdefghijklmn
pqrstuvwxyzabc
defghijklmnopq
```

The `RS` must be set to a *pattern* not present in archive, following [Denis Shirokov](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Readfile-Function) suggestion on the docs (**Thanks @EdMorton**):

```
$ gawk '{print ">>>"$0"<<<<"}' RS='^$' file
>>>abcdefghijklmn
pqrstuvwxyzabc
defghijklmnopq

abcdefghijklmn
pqrstuvwxyzabc
defghijklmnopq
<<<<
```

The *trick* is **in bold font**:

> It works by setting RS to `^$`, a regular expression that will never
>   match if the file has contents. gawk reads data from the file into
>   tmp, attempting to match RS. **The match fails after each read, but fails quickly, such that gawk fills tmp with the entire contents of the file**

---

So:

```
$ gawk '{gsub(/\n/,"");print substr($0,8,10)}' RS='^$' file
```

Returns:

```
hijklmnpqr
```

Comment: Thanks for this @klashxx. So could you explain what this RS is doing?

Comment: And is the file going as a whole to the input for awk?

Comment: Wow!! @klashxx wish I could give a thousand vote up to this. Never came across this utility (RS). Also it's fun reading your github documentation on awk. Thankyou so much :)

Comment: I want to direct the entire content of the file at once, such that with the example given I could print the 10 characters starting at index 8 taking the whole file's content into the picture (and not execute awk on each line of the file one by one generating a completely different output) . The example problem in the question is just a testcase to clarify what exactly I wanted to do. Comparatively new to bash programming I am here to learn from you guys.

Comment: To what I know is only because it is performing the operation on each line. But truly I would wish to hear "why?" from you if you please..

Comment: Awk of all varieties, including the awful (non-xpg4) one on Solaris, support character escape \b for both input and output.  IMO using a constant that will never match is more direct than  using a pattern, and eliminates ambiguity of using delimiter-specific markers ^ and $ before the delimiter is set.  Backspace binary character \b isn't going to be present in any text file.

Answer (score 3):

With GNU awk for multi-char RS (best approach):

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' '{print substr($0,8,10)}' file
hijklmn
pq
```

With other awks if your input can't contain NUL characters:

```
$ awk -v RS='\0' '{print substr($0,8,10)}' file
hijklmn
pq
```

With other awks otherwise:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0 ORS} END{print substr(rec,8,10)}' file
hijklmn
pq
```

Note that none of those produce the output you say you wanted:

```
hijklmnpqr
```

because they do what you say you wanted (a newline is just another character in your input file, nothing special):

```
"read file as a whole"
```

To get the output you say you want would require removing all newlines from the file first. You can do that with `gsub(/\n/,"")` or various other methods such as:

```
$ awk '{rec = rec $0} END{print substr(rec,8,10)}' file
hijklmnpqr
```

if that's **really** what you want.

Comment: You are correct, i exactly wanted this thing.. I posted first ten characters as an example output, but all i wanted is to read the file as a whole.

Comment: OK, you got it but just be aware that reading the whole input into memory like that is rarely the right solution to any problem.

Comment: Just a last quick question.. Is it that awk by default has `RS='\n'`?

Comment: No, awk by default uses whatever represents a newline in your OS as the RS value. On UNIX that's the character `\n`, on Windows it's the pair of characters`\r\n`. Note that means if you have a file created on WIndows then awk on WIndows will handle it's `\r\n` line endings correctly, but if you then ship that file to UNIX and run awk on it there then awk will not do what you want with it until after you run `dos2unix` or similar on your input file to convert the `\r\n` line endings to just `\n`s.

Comment: Thanks for everything :)