# Why does this pattern fail in awk?

Tags: regex, xml, awk

I try to print a captured group, but `awk` failed to capture it. My regex syntax seems nothing wrong. Is there something I missed?

Here's the text:

```
<key>NetworkServices</key>
<dict>
    <key>44412617dfsretret44rewtrtA2</key>
    <dict>
        <key>com.fdgfdgfg.ew3rer.gggfgfdgfg</key>
        <dict>
            <key>endpointProtocols</key>
            <array>
                <string>UDP:443:1450</string>
                <string>TCP:443:1450</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <key>DNS</key>
        <dict>
            <key>__INACTIVE__</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
        <key>UserDefinedName</key>
        <string>4ghgfggfddg</string>
        <key>IPv6</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ConfigMethod</key>
            <string>Automatic</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Interface</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>VPN</string>
        </dict>
        <key>__INACTIVE__</key>
        <true/>
        <key>VPN</key>
        <dict>
            <key>DisconnectOnIdle</key>
            <integer>0</integer>
        </dict>
        <key>IPv4</key>
        <dict>
            <key>ConfigMethod</key>
            <string>VPN</string>
        </dict>
        <key>Proxies</key>
        <dict>
            <key>__INACTIVE__</key>
            <true/>
            <key>FTPPassive</key>
            <integer>1</integer>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>DF6rftr34354tergsdfsdf1D9</key>
    <dict>
        <key>Interface</key>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>fgfdgfgfgr</string>
            <key>Hardware</key>
            <string>cfghfhgrCenter</string>
            <key>DeviceName</key>
            <string>ip1</string>
```

And here's my code:

```
cat /var/text.txt |  awk 'match($0, /<key>NetworkServices<\/key>.*<key>(.*)<\/key>.*<key>Interface<\/key>.*<\/key>.*<string>ip1<\/string>/) {print substr($0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1)}'
```

It should print `DF6rftr34354tergsdfsdf1D9`, but it didn't.

Thanks in advance.

Here's the tested screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Could you please do let us know which `<key>` block you want to print, what are the conditions for it?

Comment: Which version of Awk are you using?  The GNU Awk manual on [regular expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Regexp) doesn't seem to mention capturing groups — but the example with `gensub` in [string manipulation functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#String-Functions) shows them at work.  That is a GNU extension function though; it implies that `sub` and `gsub` do not do the same.

Comment: Also, remember that Awk works on single lines by default.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the gawk guys decided to leave sub() and gsub() POSIX-compliant for backward compatibility and portability to other awk variants which is why they introduced gensub() for capture groups and to be able to operate on a string literal and to return the modified string (i.e. for a sed-like sub() function). They also introduced the immensely useful 3rd arg to match() to populate an array with the capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two issue need to be addressed: The pattern is expected to match against the complete document, and the pattern is using groups to select the value.

The first issue can be solved by specifying a pattern that can not exists in the data. Using '<>' in this case. See [Awk to read file as a whole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250592/awk-to-read-file-as-a-whole) for more information.

The second issue is that RSTART, RLENGTH capture the information about the complete match. Given that the matched pattern is specified by a group (group 1 in this case), the 3 parameter version of match is needed, and the start, length value should be picked from the group 1 data. The sample solution uses the `a` array to capture group information.

This will work only with GNU awk.

```
cat /var/text.txt |  awk RS='<>' '
match($0, /<key>NetworkServices<\/key>.*<key>(.*)<\/key>.*<key>Interface<\/key>.*<\/key>.*<string>ip1<\/string>/, a) {
    print substr($0, a[1, "start"], a[1, "length"]) 
}'
```

As a side note, suggesting (1) storing each the dict key/value pair into single XML element, and (2) using XML tool to parse the whole document. It will make the task easier. For example, using Java notation for map entries:

```
<dict>
   <entry>
      <key> key </key>
      <dict>
     </dict>
   </entry>
<dict>
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you! Although I have to modify the line a little to works on my environment: `cat /var/text.txt | awk 'BEGIN {RS="<>";}
match($0, /<key>NetworkServices<\/key>.*<key>(.*)<\/key>.*<key>Interface<\/key>.*<\/key>.*<string>ip1<\/string>/, a) {
    print substr($0, a[1, "start"], a[1, "length"]) 
}'`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think **awk** is the right tool to perform this because it is aimed to work line by line. Since your pattern spans several lines and you have a XML file, take profit of the powerful structure of XML.

So, if you want to print the text node under the tag  that satisfies some condition, select it with an *xpath* expression.

According to the regex you wrote above, I will suppose the you are looking for the tag `<key>` containing the text "NetworkServices", then you go to the next node, tagged `<dict>`, then you find the `<key>` node you look for, you remember the text (it is what you are looking for) and verify that it is followed by `<key>Interface</key>`, further you go to the next node tagged `<dict>` where you have to check for the presence of a node `<key>DeviceName</key>` followed by `<string>ip1</string>`.

Here is the code I would use making a selection with **xpath** according to this:

```
/usr/bin/xpath -q -e '
  //key[text()="NetworkServices"]/following-sibling::dict[1]
    /key[
      following-sibling::dict[1]/key[
        text()="Interface" and 
        following-sibling::dict[1]/key[
          (text()="DeviceName") and (following-sibling::string[1]/text()="ip1")
        ]
      ]
    ]
    /text()
' input.xml
```

Comment: `it is aimed to work line by line` - no, awk works record by record. A newline is just the default record separator but you can easily redefine that to operate on multi-line records. I'm not disagreeing that you should use an xml-aware tool, just that specific statement about awk. There's also a GNU awk XML library if anyone cares.

Comment: @EdMorton: exactly, I meant that **awk** is aimed to work record by record. But if you have only one record, you don't have any added value to use awk just as a wrapper to perform a regex search.

Comment: As opposed to doing what? As one example - if your matching string is multiple lines long then you can't use grep, nor can you use a POSIX sed so awk is the best fit for that even if there's just one record in the file. You may also benefit from using match or tolower/upper or several other functions awk provides.