# Print Filename and Substring to csv For Each File in a Directory,

Tags: for-loop, awk, cat

I've been trying to teach myself awk to accomplish the following, but haven't had much success.

I have a directory with several text files:

```
JV-01_S01_L007_R2_002_RepetitiveText_ToRemove.txt
JV-26_S48_L_RepetitiveText_ToRemove.txt
...
```

The structure of each text file is as follows.  ***The numbers may change***, but the accompanying text will always remain the same.

JV-01_S01_L007_R2_002_RepetitiveText_ToRemove.txt

```
4620178 reads; of these:
  4620178 (100.00%) were unpaired; of these:
    1226814 (26.55%) aligned 0 times
    3040861 (65.82%) aligned exactly 1 time
    352503 (7.63%) aligned >1 times
73.45% overall alignment rate
```

JV-26_S48_L_RepetitiveText_ToRemove.txt

```
1601831 reads; of these:
  1601831 (100.00%) were unpaired; of these:
    58800 (3.67%) aligned 0 times
    1344724 (83.95%) aligned exactly 1 time
    198307 (12.38%) aligned >1 times
96.33% overall alignment rate
```

For each file in this directory, I want to compile a csv with:

```
Sample                  Total_Reads Uniquely_Mapped_Reads   Multi_Mapped_Reads  Unmapped_Reads
JV-01_S01_L007_R2_002   4620178     3040861                 352503              1226814
JV-26_S48_L             1601831     1344724                 198307              58800
...
```

Is there any way to do this with a single for loop with awk?  I was trying to use the match function.
For instance, if I could specify that match search within a specific line, and then search from left to right for a substring composed of any number of digits until a space is found.  That would grab the substring of interest for that line.

Something along the lines of:

```
for file in *.txt
do
  awk 'FNR == 1 {print FILENAME, match(NR==1, \d), match(NR==4, \d), match(NR==5, \d), match(NR==3, \d) } ' $file >> Names.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an easy way, *but it Requires GNU awk for multi-char RS*.

You can read the file as a single record using the trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43250890/2229272). Then you just need to print out the fields you want (and this does depend on your assertion that the text is fixed)

```
$ awk -v RS="^$" '{print FILENAME, $1, $16, $22, $11}' jv-01 jv-26
jv-01 4620178 3040861 352503 1226814
jv-26 1601831 1344724 198307 58800
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU awk for multi-char RS.

Comment: I'm use Mac OS, so I wasn't optimistic about having gawk.  However, it appears that gawk is a recommended command within terminal.  Should I simply use your code with "gawk -v ..." on Mac OS?  I did install homebrew awhile back - maybe gawk came with?

Comment: I should also say that adding "jv-01" and "jv-26" manually to the script isn't ideal - there are hundreds of files that I need to run this through.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  print "Sample                  Total_Reads Uniquely_Mapped_Reads   Multi_Mapped_Reads  Unmapped_Reads"
}
FNR==1{
  if(total_reads){
    print file,total_reads,Uniquely_Mapped_Reads,times,Multi_Mapped_Reads,Unmapped_Reads
  }
  total_reads=Uniquely_Mapped_Reads=times=Multi_Mapped_Reads=Unmapped_Reads=""
  sub(/_RepetitiveText.*/,"",FILENAME)
  file=FILENAME
}
/reads; of these/{
  total_reads=$1
  next
}
/aligned exactly 1 time/{U
  niquely_Mapped_Reads=$1
  next
}
/aligned >1 times/{
  Multi_Mapped_Reads=$1
  next
}
/aligned [0-9]+ times/{
  Unmapped_Reads=$1
}
END{
  if(total_reads){
    print file,total_reads,Uniquely_Mapped_Reads,times,Multi_Mapped_Reads,Unmapped_Reads
  }
}
'  *.txt | column -t
```

Comment: @JVGen, this solution should work with normal awk also doesn't need any specific version of it.