# How to remove pattern line if next line is empty using sed

Tags: awk, sed

This file, `file.txt`:

```
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected
open something

checking
open something

checking
open something
connected
open something
```

Needs to be like this, `file.txt`:

```
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected

checking

checking
open something
connected
```

We have attempted many sed one liners but with no success.

`sed -i "/open/{$!N;/\n.*^$/!P;D}" file.txt`

Where `open` is the pattern, and `^$` is the empty line after pattern.

We would like to delete only the `open` pattern matching line - if the line after it is empty.

Can someone provide assistance?

Comment: Does it _have to_ be sed? How about python?

Comment: It could be python. It's got to go into a bash shell script...

Comment: In your example every line before an empty line is `open` so do you really need to test for `open` or just delete whatever line is at the end of each paragraph? If there are cases where you don't want to delete the lat line of each paragraph then include at least one of those in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GNU `sed` has the `-z` option:

```
sed -rz 's/(^|\n)open[^\n]*\n\n/\1\n/g' file.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sed works on *one line only*. To do anything on more lines, you have to buffer them in hold space. Let's keep previous line in hold space and just iterate one by one.

```
sed '
/^$/{
  x
  /open/{
     # Just restart cycle, the line is already in hold space.
     d
  }
  x
}
x
${
    # When it is the last line, print this line and next line.
    p
    x
}
'
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative `awk` approach with some useful tricks...

The entire file can be made a single `record` by setting the record separator to something that cannot be in the file `RS="^$"` (see: [Awk to read file as a whole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250592/awk-to-read-file-as-a-whole)).

We can then set the field separator to lines with `FS="\n"`

Now a loop can be used to check for fields containing the required pattern (in this case, contains open `~/open/`) and simultaneously check whether the following line (field) is empty: `if ($i~/open/ && $(i+1)=="")` When both conditions are met the line can be skipped by using awk's `continue` command to jump to the next loop iteration.

Working procedure:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="^$";FS="\n";} { for(i=1;i<NF;i++) { if ($i~/open/ && $(i+1)=="") continue; print $i}  }' file.txt
```

output:

```
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected

checking

checking
open something
connected
```

As mentioned in the comment by @EdMorton below, using multiple characters in the RS declaration may only work in Gnu awk, original awk reads single literal characters as the separtor.

Comment: You should mention that requires an awk with extensions to allow multi-char RS, e.g. GNU awk, it won't work in a POSIX awk - that'd act as if the RS was the literal character `^`,

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;/\n$/!P;D' file
```

Append the following line and if that line is empty do not print the first line. If however it is not empty, print it. In either case delete the first line.

Answer (score 0):

Using an awk that removes fields when `NF` is decremented, e.g. GNU awk, and without reading the whole of the input into memory:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} {NF--} 1' file
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected

checking

checking
open something
connected
```

or if you really do need to test for `open`:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} $NF~/^open/{NF--} 1' file
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected

checking

checking
open something
connected
```

Answer (score 0):

If your file is not excessively big you might use `perl` to do simple replacement following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected
open something

checking
open something

checking
open something
connected
open something
```

(note: there is blank after last open something) then

```
perl -0777 -p -e 's/[^\n]*open[^\n]*\n\n/\n/g' file.txt
```

gives output

```
checking
open something
connected
open something
connected

checking

checking
open something
connected
```

(again there is blank line after last connected)
Explanation: options `-0777` enter slurp mode i.e. get whole file as single line containing newline characters, `-p -e` enter sed-like mode, regular expression `open` encased by zero-or-more non-newlines, i.e. whole line with open followed by double newline i.e. blank line, that is replaced by single newline.

*(tested in perl 5, version 30, subversion 0)*

Answer (score 0):

This `sed` one-liner should do the trick:

```
sed '/open/{$!N;s/.*\n$//;}' file
```

This doesn't use the `-z` option of GNU `sed` (thus, doesn't *slurp* the file) and should work in any `sed`.